# Shiny app path error

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny, ocr

I am trying to create an shiny app that uploads an image and then does OCR. The upload part seems to work but the OCR gives an error ***"Error: path must be URL, filename or raw vector"***     Any help is appreciated.

On another but related note, is anyone familiar with the implementation of MSER algorithm in R? I know I can call the python implementation through R.

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)
library(magrittr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
 titlePanel('Test Code'),
 sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput(inputId = 'files', 
            label = 'Select an Invoice',
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept=c('image/png', 'image/jpeg')),
  imageOutput('images')
),
mainPanel(

textOutput('extracted')

)
)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$files <- renderTable(input$files)

files <- reactive({
files <- input$files
files$datapath <- gsub("\\\\", "/", files$datapath)
files
})


output$extracted<-renderText({
text <- image_read(list(src = files()$datapath[1])) %>%
  image_resize("2000") %>%
  image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
  image_trim() %>%
  image_ocr()
  cat(text)


})

output$images <- renderImage({
        list(src = files()$datapath[1],
             height = 800,
             width  = 600,
             alt = "Upload an Invoice in an image format")
      }, deleteFile = FALSE)

}
)


 shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Your second question "who's familiar with MSER", is not really appropriate for the StackOverflow format (two questions in one, and way too vague). Or maybe you can precise it in a separate question on the site.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will create a new post. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix `output$extracted` as follows:

```
  output$extracted <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    # Fix file path
    text <- image_read(files()$datapath[1]) %>%
      image_resize("2000") %>%
      image_convert(colorspace = 'gray') %>%
      image_trim() %>%
      image_ocr()
    # Print to the console
    cat(text)
    # Return value to be rendered in Shiny
    text
  })
```